# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kucoin.client'

Tags: python, kucoin

I am getting the error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kucoin.client'; 'kucoin' is not a package" when running the code underneath. I did pip install like in the documentation here: hhttps://python-kucoin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ . What is going wrong?

````
import api_KuCoin
Xkey = api_KuCoin.Pkey
Ykey = api_KuCoin.Skey
Zkey = api_KuCoin.Dkey
client = Client(api_key=Xkey, api_secret=Ykey, api_passphrase=Zkey)```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\Crypto\kucooin.py", line 1, in <module>  
from kucoin.client import Client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kucoin.client'
````

Comment: try `pip3 install python-kucoin` for python3

Answer (score 2):

This error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kucoin.client'; 'kucoin' is not a package` may also occur if you have named the main program file you created as `kucoin.py` and try to run it as `python kucoin.py` or another file has the name `kucoin.py` in the same folder from which you run your program. Python will consider your program file as a module and try to find something in it that is naturally not in it. About where Python is looking for modules, see [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).

In this case, rename your program file so that its name does not equal with the name of the imported module.